# How to plot final c50 decision tree model (library C50) from caret::train object

Tags: r, decision-tree, r-caret, c5.0

I trained **Decision Tree** model using **train** function from **caret** library:

```
gr = expand.grid(trials = c(1, 10, 20), model = c("tree", "rules"), winnow = c(TRUE, FALSE))
dt = train(y ~ ., data = train, method = "C5.0", trControl = trainControl(method = 'cv', number = 10), tuneGrid = gr)
```

Now I would like to plot **Decision Tree** for the final model. But this command doesn't work:

```
plot(dt$finalModel)

Error in data.frame(eval(parse(text = paste(obj$call)[xspot])), eval(parse(text = paste(obj$call)[yspot])),  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 4160, 208, 0
```

Someone already asked about it here: [topic](https://github.com/topepo/caret/issues/855)

Suggested solution was to use **bestTune** from the fitted **train** object to define the relevant **c5.0 model** manually. And then plot that **c5.0 model** normally:

```
c5model = C5.0(x = x, y = y, trials = dt$bestTune$trials, rules = dt$bestTune$model == "rules", control = C5.0Control(winnow = dt$bestTune$winnow))
plot(c5model)
```

I tried to do so. Yes, it makes possible to plot **c5.0 model**, **BUT** predicted probabilities from **train** object and manually recreated **c5.0 model** don't match.

So, my question is: is it possible to extract final **c5.0 model** from **caret::train** object and plot this **Decision Tree**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The predicted probabilities should be the same, see below:

```
library(MASS)
library(caret)
library(C50)
library(partykit)

traindata = Pima.tr
testdata = Pima.te

gr = expand.grid(trials = c(1, 2), 
model = c("tree"), winnow = c(TRUE, FALSE))

dt = train(x = traindata[,-ncol(testdata)], y = traindata[,ncol(testdata)], 
method = "C5.0",trControl = trainControl(method = 'cv', number=3),tuneGrid=gr)

c5model = C5.0.default(x = traindata[,-ncol(testdata)], y = traindata[,ncol(testdata)], 
trials = dt$bestTune$trials, rules = dt$bestTune$model == "rules", 
control = C5.0Control(winnow = dt$bestTune$winnow))

all.equal(predict(c5model,testdata[,-ncol(testdata)],type="prob"),
predict(dt$finalModel,testdata[,-ncol(testdata)],type="prob"))
[1] TRUE
```

So I would suggest you double check whether the predictions are the same.

The error you see plotting the final model from caret comes from what is stored under $call which is weird, we can replace it with a call that would work for the plotting:

```
plot(c5model)
```

[image]

```
finalMod = dt$finalModel
finalMod$call = c5model$call
plot(finalMod)
```

[image]

Or you can rewrite it like you would with the results from your training but you can see it gets a bit complication with the expression (or at least I am not very good with it):

```
newcall = substitute(C5.0.default(x = X, y = Y, trials = ntrials, rules = RULES, control = C5.0Control(winnow = WINNOW)),
list(
X = quote(traindata[, -ncol(traindata)]),
Y = quote(traindata[, ncol(traindata)]),
RULES = dt$bestTune$model == "rules",
ntrials = dt$bestTune$trials,
WINNOW = dt$bestTune$winnow)
)

finalMod = dt$finalModel
finalMod$call = newcall
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, it works! I think that I found the cause of mismatch of probabilities. When I define train function like this: train(data[,-10], data[,10]) probabilities match with probabilities from c5 model. But when I use this syntax: train(y ~., data=data) probabilities don't match. In your example both syntaxes work fine, I don't know why.

Comment: I found information about 2 methods of defining variables: "When using the formula method, factors and other classes are preserved (i.e. dummy variables are not automatically created). This particular model handles non-numeric data of some types (such as character, factor and ordered data)." (https://topepo.github.io/C5.0/reference/C5.0.html).

Comment: I see.. yeah i see the factor being written again in the call. Thanks for sharing the link. Hope everything works now for you?